# what is __SGI_STL_PORT?

Tags: c++, stl

I've been looking over some code for a class and I see in one place it has this line:

```
#ifndef __SGI_STL_PORT
```

What is __SGI_STL_PORT ?
When will this be defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a "feature test macro"; it will be defined when using the STL port implementation of the standard template library (so, for example, if you include <vector> and it was provided by the STL port version of the library, then this macro will be defined). This can be useful for taking advantage of implementation-specific extensions which are not guaranteed to exist by the C++ standard.

Comment: +1, also that could be a macro defined by the code that uses the library. For example see this http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html - depending on what preprocessor symbols the user defines in his build he will get different behavior of the library.